# How can I add a Load more button in html

Tags: python, html, loops, for-loop, django-templates

I am trying to create a **load more** posts button on my django site. I want 10 posts to show at first, and then after ever 10 posts the load more button appears, loading 10 posts at a time. I also want the load more **button to disappear if there are no more posts** left to load. With the code below.

```
        {% for act in acts %}
                <div class="blog-item">
                    <div class="bi-pic">
                        <img src="{{act.image.url}}" alt="{{act.alt}} height="320" width="320"">
                    </div>
                    <div class="bi-text">
                        <div class="label">Article</div>
                        <ul></ul>
                        <div class="fp-text">
                           <h3>{{act.title}}</h3>
                        </div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>by <span>{{act.writter}}</span></li>
                            <li>{{act.date}}</li>
                            <li>20 Comment</li>
                        </ul>
                        <p>{{act.article | truncatechars:248}}
                        </p>
                        <div class="load-more-btn">
                          <a href="{{act.slug}}">read more</a>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </div>
               {% endfor %}
```